# Publishing a new BPMN Diagram that calls in an activity to a procedure - i got a Failed: Workflow Programs Compilation

Tags: genexus

I´m new on Gxflow. Changing a BPMN diagram an asociate a procedure to an activity in a BPMN diagram to publish and executing a Build All i got "Failed: Workflow Programs Compilation".Procedure has a one input parm that is a data parm inside BPMN diagram.

Please help me

Just publish new changes on BPMN diagram